# Select distinct set of values from related table in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

Sorry I'm a newbie with NHibernate I hope I don't embarrass myself with this question.

I have 2 objects, a Log and a UserProfile, in Logs and UserProfiles tables respectively.  Each Log object references one or none UserProfile objects.

I want an efficient way of collecting a distinct list of `UserProfile.UserName` strings from the Logs table, ordered alphabetically.  With Linq this is fairly straightforward, but I want this done database-side.  What would my

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetUserNamesInLogs(){}
```

look like?

If I was writing this in SQL, I would do something like this:

```
select distinct
    u.UserName
from
    Logs as l
inner join
    UserProfiles as u
    on u.UserId = l.UserId;
```

I am looking for the equivalent in NHibernate.  I think I don't want lazy loading for this (it seems like a performance drain) but I may not be clear on how the lazy loading works.

Comment: Are you saying you want to load log and then lazy load a collection of distinct usernames for each log OR you just want a query with ALL distinct usernames? This question is not quite clear enough

Comment: I want a distinct list of user names that appear in my log entries.  I would think I would not want that lazy-loaded, but I could be wrong.  I will add more context for my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utterly failing to get the durn thing to work the way I wanted it to with Criteria, I cheated:

```
var result = _Session.CreateQuery("select distinct profile.UserName from Log as l inner join l.UserProfile as profile order by profile.UserName asc")
    .List<string>();
```

This gave me the result I was looking for.  Thanks to the people who helped though.

Answer (score 2):

Some optimization for jbl answer:

```
UserProfile userProfileAlias = null;
Log logAlias = null;

session.QueryOver(() => userProfileAlias)
              .JoinAlias(() => userProfileAlias.Logs, () => logAlias)
              .Select(
                  Projections.Distinct(Projections.Property(() => userProfileAlias.Name))))
              .OrderBy(() => userProfileAlias.Name).Asc
              .List<string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Difficult to answer without classes and mappings. 
Assuming you mapped a *Logs* collection property corresponding to a UserProfile's Logs in your *UserProfile* class, your class and mapping for UserProfile should look like :

```
public class UserProfile
{
...

public virtual IList<Log> Logs {get;set;}

...
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
   <hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="true" >
  <class name="blabla.UserProfile, blabla" table="UserProfiles">

  .....
  <bag name="Logs" fetch="select" inverse="true" access="property" lazy="true">
    <key column="UserId"/>
    <one-to-many class="blabla.Log, blabla"/>
  </bag>

............
```

, you can try something like this :

```
UserProfile upAlias=null;

var result = yourNHSession.QueryOver<UserProfile>(() => upAlias)
              .JoinQueryOver(x => x.Logs)
              .Select(
                  Projections.Distinct(
                     Projections.ProjectionList()
                     .Add(Projections.Property<UserProfile>(x=>x.Name))))
              .OrderBy(() => upAlias.Name)
              .Asc
              .List<String>().ToList();
```

Comment: Hmm... actually I mapped a `UserProfile` class to my Log class.  Does that make a difference?  And wow, that looks complicated.

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs : edited my post, hope this will help. When adding projections/distinct over projections/ sort over projections, it quickly gets complicated ;-) Maybe there is a more simple solution.

Comment: I don't understand, why are you create alias "upAlias" and using instant of it lambda "x".

Comment: @Anton , I could not find the correct syntax to include the alias in the projection (needed to remove <UserProfile>). Thx for the tip, and sorry for the late reply.